# errors in my first flutter project, null value on startup?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build my first flutter project. It's an initial view for selecting a user from a dropdown.
The idea is that, when a user is selected, a text should show a bit of info of this user and, depending on the info, show a login buton or a logout button

But i'm getting an unexpected NULL value on launch

Could anyone help me?

thanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class UserScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserState createState() => _UserState();
}

class _UserState extends State<UserScreen> {
  String? dropdownvalue;
  Position? position;
  String? mvt;
  List<Row> _widgetList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllUsers().then((value) => {dropdownvalue = value[0]});
    getCurrentPosition().then((value) => position = value);
    mvt = "";
    _widgetList
        .add(UserSelect(mvt!, dropdownvalue!, position!, _widgetList) as Row);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'MY APP',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ))),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 11, 11),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 35, 50, 0)),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/admin');
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings,
                      color: Colors.orange, size: 25))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 11, 11),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 11, 11)),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          height: 30,
                          child: Text(
                            "SELECT YOUR USERNAME",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]),
                  ListView(
                    children: _widgetList,
                  ),
                ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  UserSelect(String move, String s, Position position, List<Row> widgetList);

  @override
  _UserSelect createState() => _UserSelect();
}

class _UserSelect extends State<UserSelect> {
  late String move;
  late String usu;
  late Position pos;
  late List<Row> _widgetList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllUsers().then((value) => {usu = value[0]});
    getCurrentPosition().then((value) => pos = value);
    move = "";
    _widgetList = this._widgetList;
  }

  //UserSelect(this.move, this.usu, this.pos, this._widgetList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
                child: Column(children: [
                  FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
                    future: getAllUsers(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        var data = snapshot.data!;
                        return Container(
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                child: ButtonTheme(
                                    alignedDropdown: true,
                                    child: DropdownButton(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0),
                                      isExpanded: true,
                                      // Initial Value
                                      value: usu,
                                      // Down Arrow Icon
                                      icon:
                                          const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                      // Array list of items
                                      items: data.map((String items) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: items,
                                            child: Text(items),
                                            alignment: Alignment.center);
                                      }).toList(),
                                      // After selecting the desired option,it will
                                      // change button value to selected value
                                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          usu = newValue!;
                                          move = getNextMovement(usu) as String;
                                          _widgetList.add(
                                              UserNextMove(move, usu, pos)
                                                  as Row);
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ))));
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
              )),
        ]);
  }
}

class UserNextMove extends State<UserSelect> {
  final String move;
  final String usu;
  final Position pos;

  UserNextMove(this.move, this.usu, this.pos);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 11, 11),
                    ),
                    child: Text("YOUR NEXT MOVEMENT SHOULD BE $move",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange))))
          ]),
      Row(children: [
        move == "ENTRADA"
            ? ElevatedButton.icon(
                label: Text("LOG IN",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                icon: Icon(Icons.login),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.greenAccent)),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (usu != "") {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cam',
                        arguments: ScreenArguments(usu, pos, move));
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                      width: 200,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      content: new Text(
                        "SELECT A VALID USER",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      duration: new Duration(seconds: 10),
                    ));
                  }
                },
              )
            : ElevatedButton.icon(
                label: Text("LOG OUT",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                icon: Icon(Icons.login),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.redAccent)),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (usu != "") {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cam',
                        arguments: ScreenArguments(usu, pos, move));
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                      width: 200,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      content: new Text(
                        "SELECT A VALID USER",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      duration: new Duration(seconds: 10),
                    ));
                  }
                },
              )
      ])
    ]);
  }
}
```

the getallusers() is a function that call an API and return a list of usernames (that works)
the getcurrentposition() is a generic geolocator function (that works)
the getnextmovement() is a function that, based on the username, calls an API and returns which move should he do (that works)

this `if (usu != "") {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/cam',arguments: ScreenArguments(usu, pos, move));` just redirects the user to a camera if an user is selected (also works)

thank you in advance!

Comment: try FutureBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getAllUsers() and getCurrentPosition() both return Future value so they may not be done at the time the widget is building.
The usu variable should not be 'late' and  initialize in the initState(), it should be nullable String and assign from the snapshot.data of the FutureBuilder.
You need another nested FutureBuilder for the pos variable and assign its value from the snapshot.data (do the same as the usu variable).
Hope this helps.

*** Answer the below comment:
I don't have all your code to check the syntax so I just update your code which has no syntax check, just to let you know the idea.

```dart
class _UserSelect extends State<UserSelect> {
  late String move;
  // late String usu;
  String? usu;
  // late Position pos;
  Position? pos;
  late List<Row> _widgetList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // not call here as it doesn't help
    // getAllUsers().then((value) => {usu = value[0]});
    // getCurrentPosition().then((value) => pos = value);
    move = "";
    _widgetList = this._widgetList;
  }

  //UserSelect(this.move, this.usu, this.pos, this._widgetList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
                child: Column(children: [
                  FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
                    future: getAllUsers(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        var data = snapshot.data!;
                        // assign usu here
                        usu = data[0];
                        // retrieve pos here
                        return FutureBuilder<Position>(
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            future: getCurrentPosition(),
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              // Asign pos here
                              var pos = snapshot.data!;
                            return Container(
                                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                    child: ButtonTheme(
                                        alignedDropdown: true,
                                        child: DropdownButton(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0),
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          // Initial Value
                                          value: usu,
                                          // Down Arrow Icon
                                          icon:
                                              const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                          // Array list of items
                                          items: data.map((String items) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: items,
                                                child: Text(items),
                                                alignment: Alignment.center);
                                          }).toList(),
                                          // After selecting the desired option,it will
                                          // change button value to selected value
                                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              usu = newValue!;
                                              move = getNextMovement(usu) as String;
                                              _widgetList.add(
                                                  UserNextMove(move, usu, pos)
                                                      as Row);
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ))));
                            } else {
                              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
              )),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! thank you a lot for your answer, but I'm no quite sure to understand where to do the change :S

Comment: Hi Nilroe, I updated the above answer.

Comment: thank you so much, that made other problems visible, but now i'm not getting that error :D

Comment: The _UserState class has that problem as well. You should fix it the same. I see another improvement is that the UserSelect class could receive usu and pos value from _UserState in its creator, it doesn't have to query data from database again.